# Managing page flow in Play! framework tags

Tags: java, playframework, page-flow

In a web app built using Play framework, I have a checkout page which lists the user's shopping cart as well as an address form. I created the address form as a tag (addressform.html) so that it can be reused.

checkout.html:

```
#{if shopcart.cartItems}
    #{shopcartview customer:customer,shopcart:shopcart/}
    #{addressform customer:customer /}
#{/if}
```

The address form has a form element `#{form @setAddressInfo()}`

which calls a controller method as below

```
public static void setAddressInfo(Long customerId,...) {
   ...
   showPaymentPage();
}
```

which if everything went well, goes to a payments page.

The problem occurs when I want to reuse the `addressform` on my `confirmOrder` page.

confirmOrder.html:

```
#{if shopcart.cartItems}
        #{shopcartview customer:customer,shopcart:shopcart/}
        #{addressform customer:customer /}
#{/if}

<a href="link_to_payment_page">editPaymentInfo</a>
```

here, if the user changes the address and submits the form, the `setAddressInfo()` method will, on successful completion open up the payments page. That is not good--the user *may not want* to change the payment info at all. Also, I am providing a link to payments page for those users who want to change payment info. I want the same OrderConfirm page to show up, so that the user can click on the `Submit Order` button.

So how do I do it? I can surely reuse the address form in this case right? Can you help me figure out how to manage page flow in this case?

Comment: simply, you could add a flag to your addressform tag saying "redirect to payment at the end or not"...

Comment: In the future please use a space after `.` and `?` (at the end of sentences), and a space *after* commas, not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a parameter, indicating where to redirect the user, to the setAddressInfo() via hidden input or via java paramater like. Both options:

```
<input type="hidden" name="urlToRedirectUserTo" value="urlToRedirecTo(maybe using @{}..)"/>
```

Or:

```
#{form @setAddressInfo("urlToRedirectUserTo")}
```

And in the action you do:

```
public static void setAddressInfo(String urlToRedirectUserTo) { 
   ...
   ...
   ...
   redirect(urlToRedirectUserTo);
}
```

There are better options to make it more typed and less error prone, but this one is probably good enough.